# How to prove that electric field on that base of hemispherical shell is perpendicular at all points?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

I'm asked about the direction of electric field at point $p_1$ and $p_2$

This is quite understandable that electric field points upwards at $p_1$ but I'm not able to digest that field at $p_2$ also points upwards[image]

Is there any proof for this result that field at the base is upwards at all points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels a bit homework-like, so I'll just give some hints.  My answer also assumes that the hemispherical shell is uniformly charged, which wasn't stated explicitly.

Suppose there was a horizontal component to the field at $P_2$, pointing outwards from the center of the "base".  This would mean that if we took the hemisphere and inverted it (so that it was concave side down), there would still be a horizontal component to the field.  And if we put the original hemisphere and the inverted hemisphere together to form a full sphere, their combined field would have a horizontal component.

Why is this a contradiction?

Comment: I had mistakenly thought that the hemisphere was covered with the flat surface. Thank you for pointing out that detail in my answer. :) However I have one question, could you explain why exactly that if the hemisphere is uniformly charged that it leads to the contradiction with the fact that it's conducting?

Comment: A conducting hemispherical shell will not support a uniform charge density.  The charges will repel each other and move toward the edges. I see no reason to assume that the field is uniform at the base.

Comment: So, if I got this correct after a long period the shell would act as a ring with some thickness? @R.W.Bird (thickness of edge that is), pls @ me when replying

Comment: @R.W.Bird:   There's no reason to assume the shell is conducting, either;  the problem statement is ambiguous.  If it's uniformly charged, then my argument is OK.  If it's conducting, then I (like you) suspect that the field will *not* be vertical as it passes through the base plane.

Comment: A full spherical  shell with a  uniform charge density has no field inside (Gauss's law with symmetry).

Comment: Michael, I finally understand your analysis.  If the identical hemisphere is attached to the original with the two, $P_2$'s , coinciding, then any field components parallel to the common surface will add; but there can be no field inside the complete sphere. So, the field at, $P_2$, (in the single hemisphere)  must be perpendicular to the surface (but not necessarily equal to the field at,$P_1$).